# Cisco routers get CPU usage percents

Tags: router, cpu-usage, cisco

I am new in Cisco Configure. 
I want to know is there a command to get CPU usage , memory usage , network usage of my Switch or Router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For network usage, the counters are located at the interfaces.

For CPU, use **show process cpu** or **show process cpu history**

Use **show ?** to find more commands